# Select query with nested relationships

Tags: postgresql, query, syntax

I have the following 3 *PostgreSQL* tables:

wallet:

```
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| id | name   | createdAt | updatedAt | locked |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+
| 1  | name_1 | ...       | ...       | f      |
| 2  | name_2 | ...       | ...       | f      |
| 3  | name_3 | ...       | ...       | t      |
+----+--------+-----------+-----------+--------+
```

order:

```
+-----------------------------------+--------+-----------+-----------+
|    id    |    rate    |   status  | reason | createdAt | updatedAt |  
+-----------------------------------+------- +-----------+-----------+
| 4aface2d | 0.00062231 | accepted  |        | ...       | ...       |
| 9289add0 | 0.00062231 | new       |        | ...       | ...       |
| b3dfe546 | 0.00062231 | completed |        | ...       | ...       |
| f70ed6be | 0.00062231 | pending   |        | ...       | ...       |
+-----------------------------------+--------+-----------+-----------+
```

amount:

```
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| id | value | createdAt | updatedAt |  orderId  | walletId |
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
| 1  | 200   | ...       | ...       | 4aface2d  | 1        |
| 2  | 100   | ...       | ...       | 9289add0  | 3        |
| 3  | 200   | ...       | ...       | b3dfe546  | 1        |
| 4  | 50    | ...       | ...       | 9289add0  | 2        |
| 5  | 100   | ...       | ...       | f70ed6be  | 3        |
| 6  | 200   | ...       | ...       | f70ed6be  | 2        |
+----+-------+-----------+-----------+-----------+----------+
```

Now I am struggling with composing a query that returns all the unlocked wallets (i.e. `locked=false`) together with all the related amounts, but where the amounts are filtered on status (e.g. only include amounts that have `status='new'` or `status='accepted'`).

I've tried something like:

```sql
SELECT *

FROM "wallet"

LEFT JOIN "amount"

ON "wallet".id="amount"."walletId"

WHERE "amount"."orderId" IN (
    SELECT id FROM "order"
    WHERE "order".status='new' OR "order".status='accepted'
)

AND "wallet".locked=false;
```

but that doesn't quite do what I want, because all wallet results are also filtered on the order status condition. I only want the amount result to be filtered on the order status condition. Is such a thing even possible? Or do I need two separate queries for this?

## Update

I think I have managed to get what I am after by changing my query to:

```sql
SELECT *

FROM "wallet"

LEFT JOIN "amount"

ON "wallet".id="amount"."walletId"

AND "amount"."orderId" IN (
    SELECT id
    FROM "order"
    WHERE status='new'
    OR status='accepted'
)

WHERE "wallet".locked=false;
```

Only thing now I am not sure about is if the `IN (SELECT ...)` part is efficient enough. I've read that when the table (i.e. "order") is relatively large then an `IN` based approach becomes slow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use `EXISTS` instead of `IN`. That's likely to perform better.

```
SELECT *
       FROM "wallet"
            LEFT JOIN "amount"
                      ON "wallet"."id" = "amount"."walletId"
                         AND EXISTS (SELECT *
                                            FROM "order"
                                            WHERE "order"."id" = "amount"."orderId"
                                                  AND "order"."status" IN ('new',
                                                                           'accepted'))
       WHERE "wallet"."locked" = false;
```

To further improve the performance of the above maybe try indexes on `"wallet" ("locked", "id")`, `"amount" ("walletid", "orderid")` and `order ("id", "status")`. Unless you have them already, of course.

Check the [plan](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-explain.html) if you're unsure which version performs better and what indexes help.

Comment: Nice one. Thanks! Forgot all about EXISTS. I don't do a lot of SQL stuff usually... And yes, was already planning to use indexes for all id's that are used in the different table comparisons.